# Type or namespace 'Linq' doesn't exist in the namespace 'System'

Tags: asp.net, json.net

I am trying to build the [Json.NET 2.0 library](http://www.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ProjectName=Json&ReleaseId=13099) to target the .NET framework version 2.0, and I am getting this error several times.  I went to add a reference to System.Linq to the project, but it does not exist in the references list!  What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Json.NET 2.0 does not support .NET 2.0. If you want .NET 2.0 support, use [Json.NET 1.3.1](http://www.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ProjectName=Json&ReleaseId=6987).

Comment: Thanks.  I find it disturbing that they have versions of Json.NET called 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5 but they do not correlate with the version of the framework.

Comment: It looks like they're trying to get Json.NET to correspond to the .NET frameworks, but are a little slow in doing so.

Answer (score 5):

System.Linq is a version 3.5 DLL; you'll need to remove references to it to compile in 2.0.